# How to determine whether one assembly was built against .net core, .net framework or .net standard?

Tags: c#

For example, given NewtonSoft.Json.dll, its build target may be for .net standard, or it may be for .net core only or for .net framework only. Could we detect its build target from dll?

Comment: Programmatically or manually?

Answer (score 4):

A tool such as [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) offers this information:

[image]

Comment: The `TargetFrameworkAttribute` is optional and not all assemblies have it. It's also possible to set a fake value. The .NET Core 3.x assemblies on my computer don't have `[assembly: TargetFramework]` set at all, weird.